# Wordpress custom Gutenberg block not working: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'blocks' of undefined

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm quiete desperate at the moment. I tried to build my first custom block for Gutenberg editor according to these tutorials:

- https://awhitepixel.com/blog/wordpress-gutenberg-create-custom-block-tutorial/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/javascript/js-build-setup/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/

I followed exactly the tutorials, but I can't even see the first example block in the Gutenberg editor. In the browser console occurs the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'blocks' of undefined  
at external ["wp","blocks"]:1  
at Object.@wordpress/blocks (external ["wp","blocks"]:1)  
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)  
at Module../src/block-zw-myfirstblock.js (block-zw-myfirstblock.js:1)  
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)  
at bootstrap:83  
at bootstrap:83
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be? Thank you for your help.

The block looks exactly like the one from the wordpress tutorial.
*block-zw-myfirstblock.js*:

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
 
const blockStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#900',
    color: '#fff',
    padding: '20px',
};
 
registerBlockType( 'zw/firstblock', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: 'Example: Basic (esnext)',
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    category: 'design',
    example: {},
    edit() {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps( { style: blockStyle } );
 
        return (
            <div { ...blockProps }>Hello World (from the editor).</div>
        );
    },
    save() {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save( { style: blockStyle } );
 
        return (
            <div { ...blockProps }>
                Hello World (from the frontend).
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

This is how I registered the block:

```
function child_theme_register_block() {
    $asset_file = include(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/gutenberg/block-zw-myfirstblock.asset.php');
    
    wp_register_script(
        'zw-myfirstblock-js',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/gutenberg/block-zw-myfirstblock.js',
        $asset_file['dependencies'],
        $asset_file['version']
        );
    
    register_block_type(
        'zw/firstblock',
        array(
            'api_version' => 2,
            'editor_script' => 'zw-myfirstblock-js',
            )
        );
}
add_action( 'init', 'child_theme_register_block' );
```

And this is the *block-zw-myfirstblock.asset.php*, which is included in the first line of the block-registering code:

```
<?php return array('dependencies' => array('wp-block-editor', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-polyfill'), 'version' => 'f87489192d38e545310e69e40f6c907c');
```

Comment: Please share your block's code so we can help.

Comment: You may have forgotten to add the `wp-blocks` dependency in your `wp_enqueue_script(...);` call, hence why I asked you to share the code you have :P

Comment: This is likely your problem: `include(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ...`. The [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) function returns _an URL_. You want to use [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/) instead when including files from the server.

Comment: Wow, this was really the problem. And I was looking for that problem the whole day. Thank you very much!

Comment: I just posted the comment above as an answer so you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely your problem: `include(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ....`

The [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) function returns *an URL*. You want to use [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/) instead when including PHP files from the server.